# How many invalid chocolate divisions are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

We have a $10\times 6$ chocolate. There are 4 people. Each person grabs one corner of the chocolate and takes a rectangular piece where they must claim the corner piece (following the lines on the chocolate grid). How many invalid divisions are there? (An invalid division is one where the 2 people on the same diagonal take overlapping pieces - their rectangles overlap - it's impossible). Note that the people don't have to take the whole chocolate, for example they can take just the corner square, each. Also, people on the same side of the chocolate, by definition choose valid divisions (such that they don't have overlaps with their neighbors, note that their pieces can touch, just not overlap).

There are $2*\binom{7}{4} * \binom{11}{4}$ solutions. Anyone know how they got that?

For example if we had a $3\times 3$ chocolate there would be 2 invalid divisions - one on each diagonal.

Comment: What breaks are allowed?  (normally in these problems, you are required to break the bar along one full coordinate line, I'm  guessing you aren't assuming that but what are you assuming?)

Comment: Yes, we break on the grid.

Comment: So...there are only $16$ possible choices?  Just look at each one.  Patterns should quickly emerge, but if they don't it's just a finite problem.

Comment: @lulu no there are $2*\binom{7}{4} * \binom{11}{4}$ solutions. I was wondering if someone knew the heuristics behind this.

Comment: Ah, I thought you had to break along one of the lines bordering the corner rectangle.  You are saying that anyone can break along any line they wish?   The only rule being that they then "claim" the piece that contains the corner rectangle?

Comment: It's all a bit confusing.  The obvious place to start is to work it out for a smaller grid.  Once you have done that, you can include that case in your post,  which should clarify the rules.

Comment: @lulu yes they only have to claim the corner piece

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity and to show your efforts.  As I suggested, you could do both by working out a small grid (say $2\times 3$) completely.  In particular:  you mention a problem with people on the same diagonal, but why isn't there also a problem with people on the same side?  If two people on the same side both choose a line parallel to their side, don't they quarrel as to who claims which section?

Comment: @lulu edited for more clarity

Comment: Still not clear.  Please edit to include a fully worked example.  I don't understand what "one on each diagonal" might mean.  If the $3\times 3$ case is trivial (though is it?) I suggest picking a different example.  As I previously mentioned, I don't understand how it works if two people on a side both choose a line parallel to that side, just to cite a specific point of unclarity.

Comment: @lulu how can I add a picture?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to ask that of, as I never add pictures.  I agree that would be a good idea in this case.

Comment: @lulu I could explain it in a picture, it would be much easier to understand

Comment: [This Meta Stackoverflow post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/1818245) shows the image button and the code for adding a picture.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

See image for the notation I will be using.

Since same side people never intersect, we get
$$x_1 + x_2 \leq 10$$
$$x_3 + x_4 \leq 10$$
$$y_1 + y_4 \leq 6$$
$$y_2 + y_3 \leq 6$$

Observation 1: If $1$ and $3$ intersect $$x_1 + x_3 > 10$$ **and** $$y_1 + y_3 > 6$$
Similary for $2$ and $4$

Observation 2: ($1$ and $3$) and ($2$ and $4$) never simulateonusly intersect.
(Write out all inequalities and see why)

Observation 3: $1$ and $3$ intersecting is analgous as $2$ and $4$ intersecting.
So, we can handle $1$ and $3$ and multiply answer by $2$

Now, for $1$ and $3$ to intersect, we get all inequalities

$$x_1 + x_2 \leq 10$$
$$x_3 + x_4 \leq 10$$
$$y_1 + y_4 \leq 6$$
$$y_2 + y_3 \leq 6$$
$$x_1 + x_3 > 10$$
$$y_1 + y_3 > 6$$

Observation 4: The $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates can be dealt with independantly.

So handling $x$ co-ordinated
Try out small cases and see answer equals $$\sum_{x_1 = 1}^{10} (10 - x_1) \cdot \frac{(x_1)(x_1 - 1)}{2}$$ This equals $330 = \binom{11}{4}$

$10 - x_1$ counts the values for $x_2$ and $\frac{(x_1)(x_1 - 1)}{2}$ counts values for $(x_3, x_4)$ pairs.

Calculate this sum by expanding out the sums and summing individdually.

There is a simpler way though. Think of this sum as $$\sum_{x_1 = 1}^{10} (10 - x_1) \cdot \binom{x_1}{2}$$

Can you see the combinatorial argument why this equals $$\binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4}$$

Similarly for $y$, we get $35 = \binom{7}{4}$ by this value $$\sum_{y_1 = 1}^{6} (6 - y_1) \cdot \frac{(y_1)(y_1 - 1)}{2}$$

So $\binom{11}{4} \cdot \binom{7}{4}$ is the number of invalid ways in which (only) $1$ and $3$ intersect.

Multiply by $2$ for $2$ and $4$ intersecting, $$ans = 2 \cdot \binom{11}{4} \cdot \binom{7}{4}$$